# create blog in react and store in backend mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, blogs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uAvo.png)

I want to create a blog like this image, I mean first text then image with own css the and then add heading with some css and then another and then table

some people say write like this

`<div> <p>loreme523</p> <img src="img.png" alt="img"/> <p>loreme523</p> <h1>heading 1 </h1> <h6>heading 6</h6> </div>` >

but I do not need like this I want, I just type heading text in my dash bord and my code automaticaly edit this and save in backend and when I call it my backend send this file and just type{ blog.file} and it work

please give some idea